# How to overcome cookies consent before entering a website?

Tags: python, web-scraping, cookies, selenium-chromedriver

I'm new into the world of data and I've learned a lot from free resources, which are not always the most helpfull places to look for techniques and I've been spinning around for a while with a webscraping taks.

I'm trying to automate my Chrome browser with Selenium (v. 4.16) and Python (3.9.18) to get players' data from "https://transfermarkt.com/". However, after instanciating the browser in my Windows 11 machine, I've got some problems to overcome the cookines consent windows at the very begging of the page, obtaining the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\jober\webscraper\test.py", line 24, in <module>
    driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element((By.CLASS_NAME,"//div[@class='message-container.cmp-banner']")))
  File "C:\Users\jober\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 742, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value})["value"]
  File "C:\Users\jober\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 348, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\jober\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: 'using' must be a string
  (Session info: chrome=120.0.6099.225)
```

The Python code used is the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time 

# Set the location of Chrome driver
path = "C:/Users/jober/webscraper/chromedriver-win32/chromedriver.exe"
s = Service(path) 

ChromeOptions = Options()
ChromeOptions.headless = False # Because we want to display our window

# Create a our web driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=ChromeOptions)
driver.maximize_window() # Maximize the screen
driver.implicitly_wait(30)

# Obtain the information of the site
website = 'https://www.transfermarkt.com/'
driver.get(website)
time.sleep(10)

# Closing the cookies' windows
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element((By.CLASS_NAME,"//div[@class='message-container.cmp-banner']")))
consent_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,value="//*[@aria-label='Accept & continue']")
time.sleep(5)
consent_button.click()

# Timer to set the time for the bot wait with the screen open
time.sleep(60)

# Turning off the bot
driver.quit()
```

Any of you know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe try using playwright instead? Playwright is a much newer python library, you should avoid using selenium, should fix your issue, works with chrome, msedge, webkit, chromium, and firefox, no webdriver required. [Documentation and Installation](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/intro)

Comment: `driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element((By.CLASS_NAME,"//div[@class='message-container.cmp-banner']")))` That looks like an XPath, not a class name.

Comment: you also have an extra set of parentheses around the arguments. That makes it a single argument containing a tuple, instead of multiple arguments.